# show activity in half and expand when pulled up in android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to develop a screen same as Contact screen in Marshmallow. Check below image

[image: when contact is clicked]

When expanded it becomes an activity like below

[image: when pulled up]

***Is there any widget in Design support library ?***

Comment: have you got any solution to your question?

Comment: i used this https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: thank you. Do u know what google contacts is exactly using!?

Comment: I don't know what they are using

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking is something like this:

https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet

or this:

http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/

or this:

https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

According to the [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-specs) you can built the bottom sheet like this:

```
new BottomSheet.Builder(this, R.style.BottomSheet_Dialog)
            .title("New")
            .grid() // <-- important part
            .sheet(R.menu.menu_bottom_sheet)
            .listener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO
        }
    }).show();
```

then under res/menu/bottom_sheet_menu.xml create this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/folder"
        android:title="Folder"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_folder" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:title="Upload"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_file_upload" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/scan"
        android:title="Scan"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera_alt" />
</menu>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the library and hint. But i was looking for any widget from design support library like CoordinatorLayout